# OnFormSubmit fails to create contacts when there are simultaneous submissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form where I need to capture students of the college contacts. The students give their feedback along with the contact details. The contact details must be stored to the Google Contacts

If there are simultaneous submissions, I miss some of the contacts being created (Which I can tally against from the response sheet)

My code is

```
function myFunction(e) {

    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    lock.tryLock(30000);

    var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
    Utilities.sleep(1000)
    var c = ContactsApp.createContact(items[0].getResponse(), '', '')
    c.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MAIN_PHONE, items[1].getResponse())
    ContactsApp.getContactGroup("New New").addContact(c)
    lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Can anyone help me to optimize the code so that contact are never failed.

I could try parsing the response spreadsheet, but I dont want to make any OK/NOT OK status in the spreadsheet data. I want it to be created from the Google Form itself and not via spreadsheet trigger

Thanks

Comment: remove `.sleep()`. Increase the trylockTime?

Comment: sleep after creating contact, not before

Comment: Maybe instead of running your function on each form submit, you can run it on a time-driven trigger (preferably at a time where you don't expect many form submissions)?